Jest detects tests locally but doesn't detect any in GitHub Actions
I have a very simple project. A math module in the project root with a factorial(of) function, and a test suite for said function in ./jest-tests/math.test.js. I set up my Jest config file to look for tests in **/jest-tests/**/*.test.js.
When I run tests locally using npm test all's well.
When GitHub Actions runs npm test Jest reports that it didn't find any tests.
I haven't the foggiest why this would happen, and I don't know where/how to start troubleshooting.
For completeness, my workflow is set up to trigger on pull request create, not push.
Environment:

Node v20.12.2
Jest v29.7.0
Windows 11
VS Code
GitHub runs Ubuntu

I've tried playing around with the testMatch and testRegex properties in the Jest config file, thinking Ubuntu might interpret it differently:

jest-tests/**/*.test.js
/jest-tests/**/*.test.js
./jest-tests/**/*.test.js
*/jest-tests/**/*.test.js
**/jest-tests/**/*.test.js (this is the only one that works on Windows; NONE of these work on Ubuntu/GitHub Actions)

I've tried setting --maxWorkers=1, --ci, --no-cache -- troubleshooting suggestions from around the web.
I've also tried to enable --debug hoping to gain some useful insight. The root and cwd paths look fine, the process correctly resolve all modules and dependencies, including the Jest config file.
Local output
 PASS  jest-tests/math.test.js
  factorial
    √ [1]! = [1] (5 ms)                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                  
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.081 s
Ran all test suites.

GitHub Actions output
  3 files checked.
  testMatch: **/jest-tests/**/*.test(s)?.js - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 3 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Now I'm out of ideas.
